# How can I remove little whitespace at the left side of my blog posts?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I am developing a website with Elementor page builder. I created a template for blog posts, and now the problem that I have is that there is little white space at the left side of blog posts when they are opened from mobile devices.
[Here](https://www.nardebangroup.com/blog/%DA%AF%D9%88%DA%AF%D9%84-%D8%A2%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AA%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%B3/#order) is link to a blog post where the problem exists.
[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqFHG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check the CSS `padding-left` of those containers. Decreasing that will make it closer to the left side of the page.

```css
.elementor-widget-wrap.elementor-element-populated {
    padding-left: 2%!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have checked all container padding and margins and set them to 0, but nothing changed. I am not CSS expert but I think it is not because of padding or margin, maybe positioning or something else.

Comment: Updated. Try that out.